# ¿Como generar un CREATE teniendo los valores en un array en PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hola a todos antes que nada buen día, esta vez acudo a ustedes por lo siguiente quiero generar la siguiente consulta en php.

```
 INSERT INTO public.vacunados_senasica(
      nombre, apellidos, edad)
      VALUES
      ('Darinel', 'Cigarroa', 24);
```

Teniendo los valores de los campos en un objeto y los datos a modificar en un array de la siguiente forma:

**COLUMNAS:**

```
 $columns = {"1":"nombre","2":"apellidos","3":"edad"}
```

**CAMPOS:**

```
$rows = ["darinel","cigarroa","24"]
```

Estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
$table = 'vacunados';
$sql=("INSERT INTO $table($columns) values ($rows));
DB::statement($sql);
```

Sin embargo esto no funciona supongo que las comillas esta interfiriendo, culaquier tipo de ayuda o enlace a alguna documentación se los agradeceria mucho.

Hola he estado trabajando en mi pregunta y he logrado lo siguiente:

```
<?php
     // INSERT INTO public.vacunados_senasica(
            //     nombre, apellidos, edad)
            //     VALUES
            //     ('Alan', 'Hernandez', 18);
            
$columns = ["id","nombre","apellidos","edad"];
unset($columns[0]);
$table = "vacunados";
$rows = ["darinel","cigarroa","24"];
$set = "";

foreach($columns as $k) {
    $set.=is_numeric($k) ? "$k," : "$k,";
}
$sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO $table($set) values (???)");
echo($sql);

?>
```

Ya logre construir la mayoria de la consulta me hace faltan los valores "values" que esto se resume en convertir mi array $rows en una cadena de strings con la siguiente estructura:

```
$newrows = 'darinel','cigarroa','24';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola después de un tiempo he logrado resolver la pregunta en cuestión, comparto la solución para que sea de guía si alguien se encuentra en la misma situación o similar.

```
  $table = 'vacunados';
    $columns = ['id', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'edad'];
    $rows = ['darinel', 'cigarroa', 24];
    unset($columns[0]); // Elimino el primer elemento de colums es decir ID ya que se genera automaticamente en mi DB
    $column = "";
    foreach($columns as $c) { // En este ciclo elimino las comas de colums
        $column.=is_numeric($c) ? "$c," : "$c,";
    }
    $newRows = "";
    foreach($rows as $r) { // En este ciclo  vereifico el dato de rows si es numerico le quito las comas y si es un string le asigno comillas simples 
        $newRows.=is_numeric($r) ? "$r," : "'$r',";
    }
    $sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO $table" . ' ' .  '(' . (rtrim($column, ',')) .')' . ' ' . "VALUES" . ' ' . '(' . (rtrim($newRows, ',')) . ');'); // Armo mi insert sql
    DB::statement($sql); // Ejecuto el insert en Laravel
    echo($sql);
```

[Puedes probar el código en esta página](https://paiza.io/es)

Comment: Si estás utilizando Laravel no comprendo por que hacer ese proceso, es como reinventar la rueda. 
creo que si utilizas las funciones que ya te ofrece el framework tu trabajo seria más rapido y sencillo.

Comment: Es una funcionalidad en específico donde el usuario crea sus propias tablas por eso no puedo hacer uso de las funcionalidades de Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
$conjunto_de_datos = [
  'nombre'   =>'Darinel',
  'apellidos'=>'cigarroa',
  'edad'     => 24
];

$query = DB::table(NOMBRE_DE_TU_TABLA)->insert($conjunto_de_datos);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta tendre en cuenta la estructura que me propones, quiza sea un poco más fácil generar lo que me propones, seguire actualizando la pregunta, gracias.